# MySQL MyISAM index causes query to match no rows; indexes disabled, rows match

Tags: mysql, index, myisam, debugging

I created a table and index as described in [this SE post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47674/how-can-lots-of-ram-128-gb-be-used-to-improve-mysql-5-5-index-creation/47734#47734), but when I query the table for a particular ID, no matches are found.  When I disable the index, matches are found.

Commands ran:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id1 int, id2 int, score float) ENGINE=MyISAM;
LOAD DATA INFILE '50-billion-records.txt' INTO mytable (id1, id2, score);
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX id1_index (id1);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable; # returns 50 billion
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id1) FROM mytable; # returns 50K, should be about 50M
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE id1 = 49302; # returns 0 results

ALTER TABLE mytable DISABLE KEYS;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id1 = 49302 LIMIT 1; # returns 1 row
```

Is this a bug with MySQL, or does this behavior make sense for some reason?

**Note:** When I ran `ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE KEYS;` just now, the command is acting like it is building an index for the first time (it's still running after 30 minutes, and memory usage is at 80 GB, which matches my setting of `myisam_sort_buffer_size=80G`.  I'll reply when this command finishes running (the original `ALTER .. ADD INDEX..` took 7.5 hours, so it may be a bit).

**Update:** Running `SHOW PROCESSLIST` indicates "Repair with keycache" is taking place with my `ENABLE KEYS` command.

**Update 2:** I killed the repair job on the original index because after several hours, the memory and IO seemed pretty constant, and I hoped if I started over, it may just work. So in second pass, I rebuilt the table and index, and after doing so, the exact same result occurs.

As requested, here is `explain` for count queries with index enabled:

```
mysql> explain select * from mytable where id1 = 49302;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable   | ref  | id1_index     | id1_index | 5       | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id1) FROM mytable;
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable   | range | NULL          | id1_index | 5       | NULL | 170331743 | Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here is explains after disabling indexes *(Note: 25 billion is correct number of records in table, not 50 billion as mentioned above)*:

```
mysql> explain select * from mytable where id1 = 66047071;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows        | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 25890424835 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id1) FROM mytable;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows        | Extra |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 25890424835 |       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Update 3:** Still hoping to solve this oddity. Is there something I can do with `myisamchk` that might fix this? Since I completely repopulated the table and rebuilt the index (i.e. starting from scratch) and got the same result, I assume this was not just some freak occurrence, and that it is due to some internal limit I'm unaware of.  On a side note, I've tried switching to Postgres for this dataset, but running into some other unrelated issues (that I'll leave to a different question), so fixing this index is still a top priority for me. Thanks!!

**Update 4:** Running `CHECK TABLE` currently. Will post back with updates as I have them

Comment: Can you post output of an `EXPLAIN` for those SELECT COUNT qrys in question, with both indexes enabled and also disabled?

Comment: @cerd - posted. I wonder what it means that the `COUNT(DISTINCT..))` query iterates over 170mil rows. If only 170mil rows are in index, that'd explain some of these results.

Answer (score 1):

## OBSERVATION #1

You have this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id1 int, id2 int, score float) ENGINE=MyISAM;
LOAD DATA INFILE '50-billion-records.txt' INTO mytable (id1, id2, score);
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX id1_index (id1);
```

This is how you should load the MyISAM table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id1 int, id2 int, score float,key (id1)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE mytable DISABLE KEYS;
LOAD DATA INFILE '50-billion-records.txt' INTO mytable (id1, id2, score);
ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE KEYS;
```

When you do disable keys, it stops the `.MYI` file from updating nonunique indexes.

During the `LOAD DATA INFILE`, the `.MYI` file will not grow because it contains no unique indexes or a primary key. This will promarily focus on loading the `.MYD`.

The `ENABLE KEYS` phase will do a read pass through the `.MYD` and linearly build all the nonunique indexes. In your case, it will build the `id1` index.

## OBSERVATION #2

As for the bug you seem to be experiencing, think of this:

- 25 billions rows
- 4 byte integer for id1
- 100 billion bytes = 93.13G
- That's bigger than the 80G [myisam_sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_max_sort_file_size)

### IMPLICATIONS

- It is possible that incomplete or aborted indexing operations could have lost index pages that should have been written to the `.MYI`.
- It is also possible that doing `DISABLE KEYS` makes your query run because the `id1` index is somehow being ignored. This could be the case since the EXPLAIN plan says `type ALL` and `Possible Keys NULL`. That's a full table scan. The SELECT query will work.
- With the keys enabled and incompletely written, some nonleaf node info being missing would lead to SELECT queries that are destined to fail because some of the `id1` values are not among the nonleaf node in the `.MYI`.

## SUGGESTIONS

Try running the LOAD DATA INFILE with my proposed code

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id1 int, id2 int, score float,key (id1)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE mytable DISABLE KEYS;
LOAD DATA INFILE '50-billion-records.txt' INTO mytable (id1, id2, score);
ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE KEYS;
```

Also, raise [myisam_sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_max_sort_file_size) to 100G

## Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-08-12 21:37 EDT

Repair By KeyCache is the result of hitting the max [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) and [myisam_sort_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_max_sort_file_size). In turn, MySQL elects to sift through keys in the keycache.

There are three(3) options you could further adjust

## OPTION #1

Set the [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) to 16K. That's the minimum value allowed.

## OPTION #2

Set the [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) to 1K. That's the minimum value allowed.

## OPTION #3

Set the [myisam_sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_max_sort_file_size) to its max value of 9223372036854775807

This should further prevent the Repair By KeyCache problem

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks Rolando!  When I rebuilt the table, I also suspected that my `ALTER` was the problem, so I followed your suggested method (`DISABLE` first, then `ENABLE` after loading data), and the problem remained. Regarding `sort_buffer_size`, doesn't MySQL support index building when the index doesn't fit in this buffer?

Comment: Yes, the index building should continue on disk. I updated my answer on further adjustments to try...