# Increase performance WITHOUT adding indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, index

I'm having a rather large table (350MB, 1.3M rows) and there are dozens of queries arriving at this table every second. Most queries are super-fast thanks to indexes - but some others aren't.

Obviously I'm using indexes for the most common queries on this table; but I always hesitated to add indexes for queries which are only performed every few seconds or even minutes. They are just a minority compared to the more important queries.

As far as I know, adding more indexes makes inserting new rows and updating existing data slower (and UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT queries happen very frequently for this table); but adding indexes also makes normal SELECT queries slower, since MySQL has to find the perfect index first and has to check more index possibilities.
Obviously, the slightly slower SELECT statements wouldn't be a problem; but I'm more worried about the UPDATE queries.
But on the other hand: I don't want these rare queries to take 1+ seconds, either.

Is there anything else I could do?
These performance heavy queries are creating temp tables and I thought about increasing the `tmp_table_size` (it's currently 16MB and I'm having 6+GB of unused RAM space). But then I read that this makes things even worse.

Join/Sort buffer sizes are already at 128/256MB
(Now that I think about it: These two variables are lower than the table size itself. That *might* be a problem; though I don't want to increase variables without knowing exactly what I'm doing.)

Comment: I wouldn't call statements "which are only performed every few seconds" rare. The are executed often enough to warrant an index. I have *never* seen a DBMS where adding an index would make the statement slower because parsing (the step where the best index is searched for) became an issue. When it comes to performance don't just assume things. Test them. Your concern about the DML is a valid one though, but I have seen only a few systems where adding an index really made the DML so bad that it had to be removed. But again: you have to test this.

Comment: A table of 350M is not large and will fit inside memory many times over in a modern system. If your query is causing temporary tables it's important to know why. Group by and Order by aggregations and sorting can be optimised for and knowing the biology of a composite key might show how you can refine your indexing strategy so that your access is optimised. Now for your configuration; you've shown that you're changing variables blindly without the knowledge of their effects. I would recommend a visit to https://tools.percona.com/wizard and ensure your config is sane.

Comment: I think your join and sort buffers are very, very high. If any query needs that much memory, you should consider rewriting or breaking down the query into many parts.

Comment: If you worry so much about index pick time use hint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Well then what about queries that are only performed every minute or every five minutes? There are queries which happen more often by about tenthousand-times, including DMLs. ... And my table has many different columns and there are quite a few different "rare" queries which sort data by many different column combinations. Indexing ALL of them *would* most likely make important DMLs slower. And I don't feel like indexing everything is always the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some posts about RAM disk and temp tables

- Jan 04, 2013 : [Is there a MySQL engine or trick to avoid writing so many temp tables to disk?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31401/is-there-a-mysql-engine-or-trick-to-avoid-writing-so-many-temp-tables-to-disk/31402#31402)
- Jan 17, 2012 : [How can I optimize my mysql setup to create my index faster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10840/how-can-i-optimize-my-mysql-setup-to-create-my-index-faster/10842#10842)
- Sep 23, 2011 : [skip copying to tmp table on disk mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532307/skip-copying-to-tmp-table-on-disk-mysql/7533095#7533095)

The basic idea would be to set set [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and [max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) to the bare minimum value so that move temp tables to the RAM disk quickly.

This would only help if your queries produce temp tables and you do not wish to tune tables and indexes. However, it is imperative to tuning queries and use indexes to produce the smallest possible temp tables before tuning the [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and [max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) options or even go the route of the RAM Disk.

Nevertheless, since you have 16GB on the server, you could set up good 2G RAM disk, configure good settings for join, sort and read buffers per connection, and sufficient RAM left for the OS.

## UPDATE 2014-11-25 11:09 EST

Your last comment

> I'm wondering what's the difference between temp tables on a RAM Disk and temp tables in "memory"? I think that's the same, isn't it? Therefore it makes no difference wheter I set tmp_table_size & max_heap_table_size to a high or a low value - RAM is used in both situations. Or am I wrong here?

It makes a big difference. Why ?

- If you set [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size)/[max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) too high, each DB Connection will needlessly glut memory (This is in addition to other per-connection buffers : [return my.conf values to sane levels (total memory footprint = 220GB)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82891/return-my-conf-values-to-sane-levels-total-memory-footprint-220gb/82957#82957)) I have seen customers set these to 100G to avoid thinking about this issue (Bad decision).
- If you set [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size)/[max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) high and queries need just a little more here is what has to happen:

  - You have [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size)/[max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) set at 64M
  - You makes a temp table that takes up more that 64M (let's say 66M)
  - Temp table reaches 64M
  - Query suspends processing
  - Temp table is migrated to disk
  - Last 2M needed is loaded into the temp table on Disk
  - Query continues processing
  - This is counted in [Created_tmp_disk_tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Created_tmp_disk_tables)
- **HERE IS MY POINT** : If you set [tmp_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size)/[max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) low on purpose (let's sa the minimum value of 1K), the temp table will materialize in the RAM Disk faster because it only has to stop and transfer 1K from RAM to Disk.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed I am already using a RAM Disk for my mysql temp dir. However, I'm wondering what's the difference between temp tables on a RAM Disk and temp tables in "memory"? I think that's the same, isn't it? Therefore it makes no difference wheter I set `tmp_table_size` & `max_heap_table_size` to a high or a low value - RAM is used in both situations. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister, tmp tables on "disk" (even if it's a RAM disk or tmpfs) uses the MyISAM storage engine by default. You can also put a limit on the size of the RAM disk. Whereas tmp tables in memory use the MEMORY (aka HEAP) storage engine, and can use up to tmp_table_size memory per thread. Also, MEMORY storage engine does not support TEXT/BLOB columns.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, have you gotten improvement from putting tmpdir on a tmpfs? I have tried it and found little to no improvement. The overhead of creating temp tables seems to be the bottleneck. The savings by using tmpfs isn't enough to fix performance issues. I suspect temp tables on disk use the filesystem cache and end up living in system memory anyway.

Comment: @BillKarwin you are right. It's just really band-aid to get around not rewriting queries and creating supporting indexes for them. I have had past clients that wanted this and were satisfied with some performance improvements. Of course, those clients had like 192GB RAM and more. RAM disks are not really for small to midsize DB Servers.